# Почему не срабатывает магический метод __get в возврате по ссылке?

Tags: php

```
class Router {

    public function init() {
        echo "-INIT";
    }
}

class Application {

    //По идее должно отработать при ->router
    public function __get($name) {
        echo "-GET";
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->router = new Router(); //свойство с ссылкой
        Framework::$app = $this;      //В хелпер линк на себя
    }
}

class Framework {

    public static $app;
}

new Application();  //Инициализация

Framework::$app     //Instance of Application
    ->router        //Но почему тут не срабатывает __get???
    ->init();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А он и не должен срабатывать, если я верно понял ваш код. Вы же определили свойство router в коде:

```
$this->router = new Router();
```

а `__get` вызывается только для "недостуных" свойств:

> Методы перегрузки вызываются при взаимодействии с теми свойствами или методами, которые не были объявлены или не видны в текущей области видимости.

Подробнее: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: Предположу что дело не в этом. Если после присвоения $this->router обратится к свойству в конструкторе, то __get сработает. Но думаю что это как-то связанно с областью видимости

Comment: @Ninazu для начала - а почему вы вообще допускаете, что дело не в этом? Написано четко - для неопределенных свойств. А у вас определено. Можно узнать на 100%: уберите строку `$this->router = new Router();` и попробуйте запустить. Если я прав - __get будет вызван. Если же нет (не отрицаю, что я могу что-то упускать) - тогда ситуация интереснее и стоит подумать еще.

Comment: @Ninazu Если не ошибаюсь, при неуказанной области видимости (как в вашем случае `$this->router = new Router();`) свойству присваивается public. Т.е. оно будет доступно при внешнем обращении и никаких поводов для вызова __get нет.

Comment: Хотел просто сделать отложенную инициализацию. В любом случае уже переписал логику теперь работает как хотелось, спасибо что откликнулись.